# c# запись из datagridview в textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

Нужно записать значения столбца из datagridview в textbox через запятую. Набросал код:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            textBox3.Text = ", " + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) + "\r\n" + textBox3.Text;
        }
    }
```

Хочу, чтобы вывело значения по порядку: Alex, Peter, Adam, Stane, Peter

Но выводит некорректно значения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где может быть ошибка в коде, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> textBox3.Text = ", " +
>   Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) + "\r\n" +
>   textBox3.Text;

Заменить на:

> textBox3.Text = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) ? textBox3.Text + ", " : string.Empty ) +
>   Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

Если цикл с первой по последнюю строку, то и прибавлять новые значения нужно к концу строки, а не вставлять в начало.

Comment: Спасибо, порядок теперь верный. Но перед первым словом в строке выводит запятую и пробел. Не подскажите, можно ли от этого избавиться?

Comment: @Georg96, поправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, всё верно!